# Android + ListView background sets background while scrolling?

Tags: android

I have a ListView that's populated via an ArrayAdapter.  Within the adapter, i set the view background color dependent on a conditional.  It works, but while scrolling the remaining rows adopt this color.  Here's some code:

```
class DateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DateVO> {
    private ArrayList<DateVO> items;
    public ViewGroup listViewItem;

    //constructor
    public DateAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DateVO> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            final DateVO dateItem = items.get(position);

            if (dateItem != null) {

                //is this my issue here? does position change while scrolling?
                if(items.get(position).getField().equals("home")){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_bg_home);
                }
                ...
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(ArrayAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the default behavior of a ListView. It can be overridden by setting the cacheColorHint to transparent.
Just add,

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

in your xml file.

For more details you can go through the [ListView Backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) article.
Here is an excerpt:

> To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. You can do this from code (see setCacheColorHint(int)) or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000. The following screenshot shows a list with android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" set in the XML layout file

EDIT : The view passed as convertView is essentially a view which is a part of the list view, but isn't visible anymore (due to scrolling). So it is actually a view you had created, and might be a view for which you had set the custom background. To solve this just make sure that you reset the background if the condition is not satisfied. Something like this :

```
if(condition_satisfied) {
    //set custom background for view
}
else {
    //set default background for view
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
}
```

Essentially if your condition is not satisfied you will have to **undo** whatever customisations you are doing when your condition is satisfied, because you might have received an old customised view as `convertView`.
That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but cacheColorHint is not my issue here, see above.