# Android listview duplicates the item on scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with one textview and a button in each row. Button background is setting using some conditions. If i have number of rows in list and scrolled, the button background get shuffling. That means on scrolling wrong background is setting as button background. How can i resolve this issue? My adapter class is as shown below:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PhotoCondtionthreeItemView item;
    Photo place = (Photo) getItem(position);

    if (convertView != null) {
        item = (PhotoCondtionthreeItemView) convertView;
    } else {
        item = new PhotoCondtionthreeItemView(context, place,
                membershipSign);
    }

    item.setShareTag(place.getLink()+"@@@"+place.getServerPhotoId());

    item.setBaseLayoutTag(place.getLink() + "@@@"
            + place.getServerPhotoId() + "@@@" + place.getIsGallery()
            + "@@@" + place.getId());
    File file;
    try {
        file = new File(place.getLink());
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (cache.containsKey(place.getLink())) {
                item.setThumbImg(cache.get(place.getLink()));
            } else {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapResizer.decodeFile(file, 50, 50);
                item.setThumbImg(bitmap);
                cache.put(place.getLink(), bitmap);
            }
        } else {
            item.setThumbImgMissing();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("PhotoCondThree ERROR", e.toString());
    }

    return item;
}
```

In PhotoCondtionthreeItemView class created the row for list. (not used xml for list row).

can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Look into the Edit part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7592294/802799). You have the exactly similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `yourListViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when data is changed

Comment: how if I use asyncTask to put JSONObject values to ListView items?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issue which is caused by the ListView re-using layout elements.  Without seeing the code that is actually setting the image to the view it's a little hard to say for sure but maybe this blog post will help...

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html