# Dynamically adding view to listview row , on scrolling it added view gets repeated

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview where I have to added data dynamically to linearLayout , as its not nessasary each row has same amount of data.

For this I have dynamically added textView to Linear layout in LiveView Adapter.
Now on scrolling textview are countinued adding!!
Any ideas how to resolve this???

This is what I'm doing.

```
static class ViewHolder
{       
    TextView itemName , itemQuantity , itemTotalPrice , attrKey , attrValue;
    CheckBox deleteCheckbox;
    ImageButton nextArrow;
    LinearLayout linearLayout , attrHolder;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.basket_list,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_item_name);
        holder.itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_item_number);
        holder.itemTotalPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_total_amount);
        holder.nextArrow = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_next_arraow);
        holder.deleteCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_checkbox);
        holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.basket_list_atributes);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else   
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  

    attributes = items.get(position).getAttributeVOs();

    holder.itemName.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.itemQuantity.setText("x"+items.get(position).getItemQuantity());
    holder.itemTotalPrice.setText("R  "+items.get(position).getItemTotalCost());

    if(CheckListActivity.flag)
        holder.deleteCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.deleteCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.deleteCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            System.out.println("CHECKED");
            if(cb.isChecked())
                holder.deleteCheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkarrow);
            else
                holder.deleteCheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.unchecked);

            checkedArray.put(position, cb.isChecked());             
        }
    });     

    holder.nextArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //To next activity
        }
    });


    for(int i = 0 ; i < attributes.size() ; i ++)
    {
        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        holder.attrHolder = new LinearLayout(context);
        holder.attrHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        holder.attrHolder.setLayoutParams(lparams);         


        holder.attrKey = new TextView(context);
        holder.attrKey.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        holder.attrKey.setText(attributes.get(i).getKey());
        holder.attrValue = new TextView(context);
        holder.attrValue.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        holder.attrValue.setText(attributes.get(i).getValues().toString());

        holder.attrHolder.addView(holder.attrKey);
        holder.attrHolder.addView(holder.attrValue);                    
    }

    holder.linearLayout.addView(holder.attrHolder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: See the below post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8410850/1441666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved removed the if(convertView == null) { }else  checking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't required to For Loop for new add row. U just change the items list and Listview adapter has notify method to changes in Listview.

You just search in Google by Listview notify changes.

Comment: No i'm not adding new row  , I'm adding linear layout in A ROW . Its like I have a list of products and each product will be having different specs ...so these specs I'm adding in loop for a particular row / product